# Bat, .Net и уровни каталогов

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, bat, c#-7.0

Довольно-таки необычный вопрос, который завел меня в тупик. Итак - есть приложение написанное на **C++** и есть приложение написанное на **.Net 7**.
Дерево каталогов выглядит так:

```
Data\Run.bat
Data\Input\
Data\Output\
Data\Win64\Bin\App-C-plus.exe
Data\Win64\Bin\App-Dot-Net.exe
```

Содержимое **.bat** выглядит так:

```
@echo off

Data\Win64\Bin\App-C-plus.exe ..\..\Data\Input -build ..\..\Data\Output
Data\Win64\Bin\App-Dot-Net.exe ..\..\Data\Input -build ..\..\Data\Output
```

Содержимое приложения на **.Net**:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0) 
            { 
                if (args[1] == "-build")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        File.Copy(args[0], args[2], true);
                        Console.WriteLine($"File copied from {args[0]} to {args[1]}");
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Вот мы и подобрались к сути вопроса: - почему данная команда в **.bat** файле для приложения написанного на **.Net** работает не так, как ожидалось:

```
Data\Win64\Bin\App-Dot-Net.exe ..\..\Data\Input -build ..\..\Data\Output
```

Но если изменить ее вот так:

```
Data\Win64\Bin\App-Dot-Net.exe Data\Input -build Data\Output
```

Чтобы получилось вот так:

```
@echo off

Data\Win64\Bin\App-C-plus.exe ..\..\Data\Input -build ..\..\Data\Output
Data\Win64\Bin\App-Dot-Net.exe Data\Input -build Data\Output
```

Все отлично работает. Причем команда для приложения написанного на **C++** работает исправно. Мы можем спокойно перейти на уровень каталога выше. Я просто не понимаю, почему стандартная *команда перехода на каталог выше*, работает не так как я этого ожидал. Не то чтобы меня это беспокоит, просто не могу найти на это ответ. То есть приложение инициализирует запуск, как будто непосредственно находится в папке **Data**.

**UPD:** Добавил код, но вариант, предложенный товарищем **@rotabor** гениален, именно что-то такое я и предпологал:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Правда я его еще не протестировал, но думаю что это то, что нужно.

**UPD-1:** Протестировал, получаю это:

```
Error: The value cannot be an empty string. (Parameter 'path')
```

Код выглядит так:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0) 
            { 
                if (args.Length == 2)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                        File.Copy(args[0], args[1], true);
                        Console.WriteLine($"File copied from {args[0]} to {args[1]}");
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Рабочий каталог (working directory) в общем случае не равен каталогу, из которого приложение было запущено. Танцевать нужно от этого факта.

Comment: Перед запуском приложения просто сделайте `cd` ему в папку. Сейчас у вас пути задвются от текущего каталога, а не от каталога с экзешником приложения. Если хотите исправить код, надо его для начала показать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Секрет как раз и заключается в строке "//Copy file here {From source to Destination}", равно как и в соотвествующей строке приложения на С++, а вы их не показали. Похоже, что последнее работает от собственного каталога, а .NET - от каталога запуска. Ну и бибилиотеки System.IO и соотвествующая в С++ могут работать по-разному.

В общем, пока удивительного ничего нет.

Вы еще позапускайте батник из командной строки из разных папок, наверняка что-то пойдёт не так.

**UPD** В документации всё подробно расписано https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=net-7.0

Пример:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace NsPathUncertanity {
    class PathUncertanity {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            try {
                switch (args.Length) {
                    case 0: Console.WriteLine("nop"); break;
                    case 1: Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(args[0])); break;
                    // case 2: Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(args[0], args[1])); break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception objException) { Console.WriteLine(objException.Message); }
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
C:\Users\auser\Documents\My Projects\Stackoverflow>ar graf.txt
C:\Users\auser\Documents\My Projects\Stackoverflow\graf.txt

C:\Users\auser\Documents\My Projects\Stackoverflow>ar ..\drum.txt
C:\Users\auser\Documents\My Projects\drum.txt

C:\Users\auser\Documents\My Projects\Stackoverflow>ar ..\..\drum.txt
C:\Users\auser\Documents\drum.txt
```

Всё работает согласно документации. Возможно, вы где-то ранее меняете текущий путь, что влияет на интерпретацию ".."

**UPD** **UPD** Если вам нужно просто повторить то, что написано на С++, то используйте

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
```

перед File.Copy

Comment: Код на **C++** к сожалению дать не могу, написан был не мной. Но суть один в один копирует базу данных **.dbf** из input в output, а на C# -код такой:
`File.Copy(Path.GetFullPath(args[0]), Path.GetFullPath(args[2]));`

Comment: Я также пробовал убирать **Path.GetFullPath()** - эффекта 0.

Comment: Посмотрю, как работает - отпишусь

Comment: Тестировал это:
`static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0) 
            { 
                if (args.Length == 2)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        File.Copy(args[0], args[1], true);
                        Console.WriteLine($"File copied from {args[0]} to {args[1]}");
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: bat. файл поместил на 2 уровня выше, используя команду из .bat - сделал так: `Debug\Bin\Test.exe ..\..\Data\in\File.txt ..\..\Data\Ou\File.txt` - результат 0. Работает только так: `Debug\Bin\Test.exe Data\in\File.txt Data\Ou\File.txt`

Comment: В остальных случаях выводит что не удалось найти часть пути, можете сами кстати проверить этот код. У вас также будет абсолютно работать.

Comment: И скорее всего у вас .bat файл находится в том же каталоге, что и исполняемый файл. А я делаю как написал чуть выше. Если запускать .bat'ник находясь в том же каталоге что и приложение, то да, все работает. А если переместить его на уровень или два повыше (без разницы) и прописать путь к исполняемому файлу , то так уже не работает. Посмотрите чуть выше что я делаю.

Comment: Про это я написал. Когда батник у вас сверху, то текущий каталог - его, и оттуда вы "..\.." на Data никак не выходите. У вас всё правильно отрабатывает. Приложение такого типа и не должно работать от собственного каталога.

Comment: Если вам нужно просто повторить то, что написано на С++, то используйте Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); перед File.Copy

Comment: Там "Path.GetDirectoryName" не хватает, добавил. См. UPD UPD. Проверил, работает.

Comment: Да, идеально сейчас работает! Видимо это какая-то специфика языка **.Net**. Я прям даю **100%** и **200%** сверху, что тот человек, который писал на **C++**, аналогично работающее приложение в 3 строчки, явно бы не стал заворачиваться над этим. А вам спасибо огромное за решение!

Comment: Это не специфика, а спецификация. Всё работает как задумано и как ожидается.